# Missing all photos

Tags: ipad, mobile-iphoto

Missing all photos on my iPad 2. Did restore from I cloud it has been nine days saying it's still restoring manually downloaded apps and music. But still no photos

Answer (score 1):

Hey there are you using iOS 8? If so, I know there's quite a few more options for photos. By default everything is under the "moments" tab.

If there aren't any photos in Moments, we should take a look and be sure your photos were backed up to iCloud under your settings > iCloud > Storage > manage storage > (your backup that you're restoring from). In this menu you should see "photo library" listed as one of your backed up items. Is it there?

Hope this helps Betty!

Comment: It's not showing anything but the apple rep says that the iCloud backup was showing. My folders are all there  but no photos. It took me around twenty seven restarts to just get it to even attempt this restore. I've had several ppl to tell me that it didn't restall untill there third attempt when they didn't get restore failed message. I had to install all my apps manually but I have none of my game progressions. Although my Game Center is still showing the levels before I did the ios8 upgradeAnd still don't have all my music and what I have I had to manually download it.

Comment: No photos at all. Just my albums.

Comment: It is still saying it is restoring from iCloud this whole process has been going on for over three weeks now.

Comment: Hmm, 27 restarts just to get the restore started? As well as all this time and the restoration isn't finished. It sounds like this would need some more in-depth investigation. If you live near an Apple store I would make an appointment with their genius bar, to ensure that nothing is going wrong with your device.